# Does Google Actions SDK currently ignore possibleIntents even for speech biasing?

Tags: actions-on-google

I see here that custom intents in `actions.json` are used for speech biasing https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedIntent

**What was expected**

I have an intent, `general.price`, that contains `high` as one of its trigger queries. I want to pass this in `possibleIntents` for purposes of speech biasing on a follow-up intent.

**What happened**

Despite passing an intent for use with speech biasing that contains the word `high`, the speech is still picked up as `hi`. Note that setting `high` in `speechBiasingHints` *does* work, but I want to leverage this feature not to pass large lists of data every response.

Has anyone got this feature to actually work?

**EDIT:**
Using DialogFlow is **not** an option. My use case aligns exactly with the Actions SDK. I simply want a sustainable way to provide lists of biases to Actions on Google, tangential to DialogFlow.

Answer (score 0):

The [ExpectedIntent](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedIntent) property of the in-dialog [AppResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse) object can only be used with [built-in intents](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/intents), most commonly the `actions.intent.TEXT` intent. Action Package [intents](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Action#Intent) can only be triggered by the user at invocation time. See [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/define-actions) for more.

For in-dialog speech recognition and biasing, we recommend [Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/#top_of_page).

Comment: We have a custom NLU system we want to integrate with, so using DialogFlow is not an option. We simply want speech biasing based on custom intents we register. The documentation says this should be possible. Should the documentation be updated?